# Retrieving rows from a third table that match two pivot tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database

I have 5 tables in my Laravel app. 3 main tables are `books`, `places`, and `tags`. The `books` table has a pivot table to relate it to tags: `book_tags`. The `places` table also has a pivot table: `place_tags`. Now, for each place, I'd like to get the books based on tags that are both in `place_tags` and `book_tags`.

```
books
    book_tags
places
    place_tags
tags
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2674d/1)

I've looked through the laravel docs and the closest this seems to come to is a [many to many polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations), but with that, there'd be only one pivot table with a `tag_type`, which is not what I have.

How would I build this query to retrieve the books for each place based on tags in both pivot tables? Answers in MySQL are cool too, I just don't know how this would look like as a query...

Comment: "Now, for each place, I'd like to get the books" You can't relate a book to a place because there isn't a relation (missing pivot_table book_place)

Comment: there is, through the tags! Lets say that a place has the tag Science, and the book has a tag Science, therefore I wanna get the books with the same tag as the place has. They have a relation through tags, where both books and places can have the same tag (tag id), but their relations are just separately defined.

Comment: Create a http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ with table structures and example data to make the question even more clear.. Also create a ascii data table with the results you expected from the example data..

Comment: You want to use https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations Exact same example is presented in the documentation; lack of research.

Comment: @RaymondNijland http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d59709/1 <-- just the schema so you can see the structure :)

Comment: @Kyslik sorry man, but you'll notice I linked to the same docs in my question and clearly outlined why that wouldn't work (see 2nd paragraph). Those polymorphic relations require a `taggable_type`. Lack of reading the question.

Comment: Yea if you want to make it Eloquent way you need to adapt schema and make it work. Pros = you can use taggable on any other entities. Cons = you need to adapt. Its tagged as Eloquent - if you need just raw query to make it work then lets hope someone willing is going to craft it for you.

Comment: @Kyslik that's another issue but I can't adapt the schema just yet so I need to make it work with what I have... There's clearly a relationship just how do I get to it :P?

Comment: "just the schema so you can see the structure :) " Only table structure?? we can't help you without example data and expected results.. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query iám vote closing this question to be unclear.

Comment: @RaymondNijland you're right was just getting the hang of SQLFiddle :) Here ya go http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2674d/1

Comment: @RaymondNijland what's unclear? I'd like to get all the books for a given place :P Data added to sql :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2674d/1

Comment: With the table structures and example data the question makes more alot more sense and i've posted a MySQL query answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I build this query to retrieve the books for each place
>   based on tags in both pivot tables? Answers in MySQL are cool too, I
>   just don't know how this would look like as a query...

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   books.*
 , places.*
FROM 
 book_tags
INNER JOIN 
 place_tags
ON
 book_tags.tag_id = place_tags.Tag_id

INNER JOIN 
 books
ON
 book_tags.book_id = books.id

INNER JOIN 
 places
ON
 place_tags.place_id = places.id
```

**Result**

```
| id |       title | id | name |
|----|-------------|----|------|
|  1 | Science Boo |  1 | Shop |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2674d/13

Or use column aliases like

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   books.id AS book_id
 , books.title AS book_title
 , places.id AS place_id 
 , places.name AS place_name
FROM 
 book_tags
INNER JOIN 
 place_tags
ON
 book_tags.tag_id = place_tags.Tag_id

INNER JOIN 
 books
ON
 book_tags.book_id = books.id

INNER JOIN 
 places
ON
 place_tags.place_id = places.id
```

**Result**

```
| book_id |  book_title | place_id | place_name |
|---------|-------------|----------|------------|
|       1 | Science Boo |        1 |       Shop |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2674d/15

> @RaymondNijland what's unclear? I'd like to get all the books for a
>   given place :P Data added to sql :) sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2674d/1

Then you need to add

```
WHERE
  places.name = 'name'
```

to the queries above

Comment: That does the trick! I also removed `places.*` since I only need the books, not the data about the places, and since I know the place-id, I skipped the last inner join and in the WHERE clause I put `where place_tags.place_id = ID`. Thanks! If you have any idea of how this would look in eloquent without doing `Raw` everywhere... :D

Comment: "If you have any idea of how this would look in eloquent without doing Raw everywhere... :D " @Michał no i don't know that..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm reading.

Assume a tags model:

```
class Tag {
      public function books() { 
          $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
      }
      public function places() {
          $this->belongsToMany(Place::class);
      }
}
```

Then if you need to get all books which have a common tag with a specific place you can do:

```
$tagsForPlace = Tag::whereHas("places", function ($query) { $query->where("id", $placeId; })->with("books")->get(); //$PlaceId is the id you are interested in.
```

Then the books you need are just:

```
$booksWithTagsForPlace = $tagsForPlace->map(function ($tag) { 
      return $tag->books; 
})->unique("id"); //Unique to filter out duplicate books if any
```

I may be wrong in my understanding of the question though.